# append files base on a list

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, sort

I have a list that corresponds to a file. These files have to be appended to a single file based on their order on the list.

```
  order.list:
  FLORIDA        #corresponding file is florida.txt
  ILLINOIS       #corresponding file is illinois.txt
  UTAH           #corresponding file is utah.txt
```

Using the `order.list` above, i have to append the `.txt` files using the order utah.txt, followed by florida.txt then illinois.txt

```
  scenario 1:
  order.list:
  UTAH
  FLORIDA
  ILLINOIS

  cat utah.txt >> final.txt
  cat florida.txt >> final.txt
  cat illinois.txt >> final.txt

  scenario 2:
  order.list:
  ILLINOIS
  UTAH

  cat illinois.txt >> final.txt
  cat utah.txt >> final.txt
```

Aside from the changing order of the list, sometimes, `order.list` can only contains two or one line.

I could try an if statement but that could take long. Is there an efficient way to handle this?

Comment: Does your `order.list` file really contain the `#corresponding file ...` comments, or is it simply one value per line?

Comment: Your very first example is out of order, I think.

Comment: no. the comments are not included in `order.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE=order.list
OUTPUT_FILE=final.txt
# Empty the output file
>${OUTPUT_FILE}

while read COUNTRY
do
        FILENAME=$(echo ${COUNTRY} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
        cat ${FILENAME}.txt >> ${OUTPUT_FILE}
done < ${INPUT_FILE}
```

Comment: See also `${parameter,,pattern}` for lower-casing, since we're using bash.

Comment: yes.. we can use it like   FILENAME=$(echo ${COUNTRY,,})

Comment: ... or, more simply `cat "${COUNTRY,,}.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
rm final.txt & cat order.list | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read line; do cat $line.txt >> final.txt; done
```

First, existing final.txt is deleted, than the order.list is read and converted to lowercase (according to the input you provided) and then appended in the order read.